# Trying to drag a UIImageView up and down a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView that has a UIImageView which traverses it one row at a time at the click of a button (up/down).  What I would like to do now is allow the user to drag the UIImageView up or down the table ONLY (i.e. no sideways movement).  If majority of the UIImageView is over a particular cell, then when the user lets go of their finger, then I want the UIImageView to link to that row.  Here is an image of the UITableView, with the UIImageView:

[image]

The scroll bar is the UIImageView that needs to move or down.  I realize that I am supposed to implement the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // We only support single touches, so anyObject retrieves just that touch from touches.
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] != _imageView) {

    return;
}

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];


    if ([touch view] == _imageView) {

        return;
    }
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //here is where I guess I need to determine which row contains majority of the scrollbar.  This would only measure the y coordinate value, and not the x, since it will only be moving up or down.
        return;
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure HOW to achieve this functionality.  I have tried to find similar examples online, and I have looked at the MoveMe example code from Apple, but I am still stuck.  Please also note that my scroll bar is NOT the exact same size as a row in the table, but rather, a bit longer, but with the same height.

Thanks in advance to all who reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference) to the UIImageView. Start by getting the image view's current location, then use the `translationInView` method to determine where to move the image view.

From Apple's documentation:

> If you want to adjust a view's location to keep it under the user's
>   finger, request the translation in that view's superview's coordinate
>   system... Apply the translation value to the state of the view when the gesture is first recognized—do not concatenate the value each time the handler is called.

Here's the basic code to add the gesture recognizer:

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panView:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Then, do the math to determine where to move the view.

```
- (void)panView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];

    // Your code here - change the frame of the image view, and then animate
    // it to the closest cell when panning finishes
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution, and my apologies for the delay in responding but your solution was the approach I needed to take!